# I tried to deploy a NodeJS app on heroku and I can't make requests from the outside routers

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, deployment

I deployed my NodeJS app on heroku, but I have a problem. I can make the get request from "/", created on app.js with app.get("/", ...), but I can't make any request from the outside routers, it is loading for a time, and then an error pop up. The problem is not from the router, on local version, all requests work.

Comment: What's the error looks like ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that in your code the server is hosted on process.env.port, as heroku dynamically assigns ports in order to help keep the service free.

Comment: I am using process.env.PORT and when I'm running heroku locally(I mean using the command heroku local web), the outside routers work.

Comment: Open heroku logs on their site and see what kind of error you get when you try to load the page.

Comment: I opened and found out that the problem is request timeout, I think is because the database can't be access from heroku ip adress. I want to add it to the white list, but I don't know where to find it. Can you help me?

Comment: What database are you using? Heroku IPs are also dynamic so you are just gonna have to allow all IPs on your database (Whitelist 0.0.0.0/0)

Comment: I'm using MongoDB with MongoDB Atlas, i found in the docs something about peering info, but I can't get them, when I use the terminal command I get this error  " Couldn't find that space."

Comment: Like I said you have to whitelist every IP, create a user account in mongo atlas then connect this url, replacing the bolded variables "mongodb+srv:// **<username>** : **<password>** @main.wg2b2.mongodb.net/ **<dbname>** ?retryWrites=true&w=majority" and obviously get rid of spaces in the url which I had to include in order to bold text.

Comment: You can see all this info by clicking "connect" on your mongo cluster then clicking "connect your application"

Comment: It worked:) thanks. Is there a better choice than Heroku, maybe a host place where I can use the IP restriction?